# Discrepancies between ANOVA results and multiple linear regression in R

Tags: regression, anova

I am working on a project to determine what factors affect how much money a movie grosses, and made a multiple linear regression model in R to test for significance among my predictor variables. My linear model in R is:
`lm1 <- lm(gross ~ num_critic_for_reviews + num_user_for_reviews + imdb_score + duration + budget + title_year + content_rating, data = movie_df)`. When I do a summary of my model, I get these [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y4VN.jpg).

After interpreting the results from my linear model, I ran a factorial analysis of variance test to analyze the difference in group means in my model. When I ran the ANOVA using R's anova() function, I got these [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpcux.jpg).

I am confused as to why in my linear model the imdb_score variable was significantly related to gross, but in my ANOVA the results show that imdb_score does not affect gross. It is my understanding that ANOVA and regression are essentially the same [statistical test](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/why-anova-and-linear-regression-are-the-same-analysis/), so I am unclear as to how/why why I am getting differing results. Can anyone give me some insight into my results?

I am relatively new to working with inferential statistics, so my apologies if I am misunderstanding something here.

Comment: Have you tried standardizing the "large" variables (such as `gross` and `budget`)?  Or at least dividing those by 1,000,000 or 10,000,000?

Comment: What would standardizing or dividing the large variables do?

Comment: There is likely a lot of round-off error given the size of the numbers.  Try it and you'll likely find consistent results (and maybe even different than what you've presented so far).  If it's possible to share the data, then you'll get more specific help.

Comment: Sorry, I steered you wrong.  While theoretically scaling makes no difference, in practice it definitely can (with generalized linear models for example).  But in this case the answer is that `anova` uses Type I sums of squares in which the resulting P-values depend on the order of the terms in the model.  To get what `summary(lm1)` gets you, use the `Anova` function in the `car` package:  `Anova(lm1, type="III")`.